# Golang - How to turn an exponent and mantissa to a float64 or float32

Tags: go

I have a library that gives floats in mantissa and exponent values for no loss of precision.

```
Mantissa: 375400000000000
Exponent: -9
```

How do I turn this into a float32 or float64 in golang?

I gave it a shot here but the number is definitely not coming out correctly: https://go.dev/play/p/8wMxhq11qwS

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    mantissa := 375600000000000
    exp := int8(-9)

    var price big.Float
    mant := big.NewFloat(float64(mantissa))
    price.SetMantExp(mant, int(exp))

    fmt.Println("price: ", price.String())
    fmt.Println("mant: ", mantissa)
    fmt.Println("exp: ", exp)
}
```

Apparently this doesn't work because big.Float is represented by `sign × mantissa × 2**exponent`
when I need `sign x mantissa x 10 ^ exp`

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/math/big@go1.19.1#Float.SetMantExp

Comment: It would be nice to know what library you're using so we could read its documentation too.

Comment: @BennyJobigan Sorry, the library isn't public.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most obvious solution would be to use the `Pow10` function in the math package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    mantissa := 375600000000000
    exp := int8(-9)

    price := float64(mantissa) * math.Pow10(int(exp))

    fmt.Println("price: ", price)
    fmt.Println("mant: ", mantissa)
    fmt.Println("exp: ", exp)
}
```

This function is valid for all possible values of your exponent, but precision may be degraded depending on the value of your mantissa.

Comment: Is there another way to do it using Decimal that doesn't lose precision?

Comment: @BAR Both `big.Float` and `float32` and `float64` have precision that you have to be aware of. The only other way to handle that would be to create a custom decimal object that uses an integer value for the integer part and another for the decimal part. But if you do that then you have to determine the precision explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who's had to deal with precision issues in Go quite a bit, the `math/big` package is an excellent alternative to using `float32` or `float64`. However, it does not offer an exponentiation function. One package that does is [ericlagergren/decimal](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ericlagergren/decimal?utm_source=godoc#WithPrecision):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ericlagergren/decimal"
)

func main() {
    mantissa := decimal.New(375600000000000, 0)
    exp := decimal.New(-9, 0)

    ctx := decimal.Context {
        Precision: 9, // Set this to determine the number of expected decimal places
    }

    price := new(decimal.Big)
    ctx.Pow(price, decimal.New(10, 0), exp).Mul(price, mantissa)

    fmt.Println("price: ", price)
    fmt.Println("mant: ", mantissa)
    fmt.Println("exp: ", exp)
}
```

The upside to this package is that the result is guaranteed to the set precision. The downside is that you have to set that precision explicitly. In this example, I set a precision of 9 digits because an interim calculation would result in an output of `1e-9`, which requires 9 digits of precision.